# How to use quantmod library in Jupyter R Notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, quantmod, jupyter-irkernel

I need to call quantmod::getSymbols. The function works perfectly in Rstudio, but it doesn't work in Jupyter R Notebook:

[image]

In terms of Jupyter, I am using Anaconda environment(https://www.continuum.io/downloads), with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

This series has missing values written as `.` (full stop) which might cause the problem in Jupiter. But you can always download the data from within Jupyter using `read.csv` and replace the problematic values with `NA` and `na.locf` .

```
url <- "https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=USD1MTD156N"
tail(read.csv(url, header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
           DATE USD1MTD156N
8059 2016-11-22     0.58422
8060 2016-11-23       0.592
8061 2016-11-24     0.60256
8062 2016-11-25     0.60589
8063 2016-11-28     0.60561
8064 2016-11-29     0.61672
```